# How to assert list of values in ascending order?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Here is a list of values in an array:

```
[463, 246, 216, 194, 154, 152, 147, 140, 129, 128, 123, 118, 118, 102, 102, 101, 97, 96, 93, 85]
```

How can I ensure/assert through RSpec that the array list is in ascending order?

Comment: `list == list.sort`?

Comment: Providing an example in a question is generally helpful, but the inclusion of an arbitrary numeric array that is not referenced by the question serves no purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is probably:

```
expect(array.sort).to eq(array)
```

Comment: To assert that it is in strictly ascending order, add a separate test `expect(array.uniq.size) == array.size`.

Comment: Yes @IIya that makes sense :)

Comment: [`Array#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sort) is *not* stable, so this does not work if there are equal elements.

Comment: `Array#sort` is stable in the context of this question (array of ints).

Answer (score 1):

"Ascending" means "the next element is not smaller than the current". You can encode that into a predicate easily:

```
expect(array.each_cons(2).all? {|a, b| a <= b }).to be_truthy
```

Note that [`Array#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sort) is *not* stable, so something like

```
expect(array.sort).to eq(array)
```

*does not work*!

Comment: Could you please provide an instance, when sort does not work, but your answer works?  Also, `be_truthy` is __not nil or false__,  `be true` is enough.

Comment: `sort` is unstable, which means that if there are elements where `<=>` returns `0`, there is no guarantee that they will keep their relative order. There is also no guarantee that for elements where `<=>` returns `0`, `==` returns `true` (although I would consider that very strange if not a bug, but hey, people do strange things). So, if there are two elements which have the same order but are not equal, then they may get swapped by sorting and resulting in the original array and the sorted array to not be equal.

Comment: But there are only integers in the question, I think your answer is overhead in this context, but, of course, makes sense in some (very rare) conditions.